# how to embed groovy script in html like in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, groovy

is it possible to embed groovy script in html like in javascript?
I want to have an onclick button event that use groovy script instead of javascript

Thanks

Comment: Groove is for Java right? It is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: removed Java and PHP tags. As far as I can see, this has nothing to do with either.

Answer (score 5):

You can't

You could use AJAX to call the webserver which would run a groovy script, but you can't run groovy in the browser like JavaScript.

<sub>(For completeness in this answer, I guess you could roll an applet with groovy support, and then use the applet to execute bits of groovy, but I would just write the script in javascript and miss out this sort of Rube-goldberg machination)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather old project, and I'm not sure quite how far it actually went, but [Andres Almiray](http://jroller.com/aalmiray/) has [done](http://jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/running_groovy_on_an_applet) [some](http://jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/more_on_groovy_applets) [work](http://www.jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/live_grapplet_test) on getting the ability to run Groovy in the browser, via [Grapplet](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grapplet).

I haven't used it myself, but it looks promising.